# PHP removing a certain string in a string once

Tags: php, string

I recently have played around with the use of preg_replace in PHP to specifically remove a string once.

However I have a list of numbers (345, 346 and wanting to remove ", 346" for example) and I have kept on running into the same problem how it removes the whole string and leaves it empty.

Desired results are

```
345, 346
Removing ", 346"
Turns to
345
And also
345, 346, 347 removing ", 346"
Turns to 
345, 347
```

Code:

```
$oldpost = ", ".$_GET['id'];

$newposts = preg_replace($oldpost, "", $row['posts']);
```

I tried this previously and haven't found anything that seems to do a better job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you have

```
$newposts = preg_replace($oldpost, "", $row['posts']);
```

where you are actually giving the entire string itself to be replaced. Hence, it gives you an empty string because your 2<sup>nd</sup> parameter is an empty string.

You can match the exact `346`(if it's present) with an optional matching of a `,` and replace them with empty string. So your regex would look like

```
/(,?\s*346(\s|,|\b))?/
```

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$oldpost = "345,346,347";
$newposts = preg_replace("/(,?\s*346(\s|,|\b))?/", "$2", $oldpost);
echo $newposts,PHP_EOL;
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/MeSeK

---

Note that above approach works fine, but the best way to solve this problem is to [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the comma separated string and unset the location in the array where have the `346` and [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it back again.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$oldpost = "345,346,347";
$posts = explode(",",$oldpost);

$index = array_search(346,$posts);

if($index !== false){
    unset($posts[$index]);
}

$new_post = implode(",",$posts);

echo $new_post;
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/qvSEN

Note that if there are multiple occurrences of `346`, you can use a simple `foreach` to unset them.

Comment: @Alex Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is here for preg_replace:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Try adding a value for the "limit" parameter.

limit:
The maximum possible replacements for each pattern in each subject string. Defaults to -1 (no limit).